# How to pass actions created with typesafe-actions createAsyncAction to a function that generates redux-observable epics with the correct types?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-observable

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to pass an AsyncAction created via CreateAsyncAction while keeping the typing information, for example in my case I am trying to create a generic GraphQL query epic using ApolloClient since all of those will have the same REQUEST/SUCCESS/FAILURE flow:

What type should the asyncAction be so that the isActionOf and the action.Payload resolve properly?

```
const createAsyncEpic = (asyncAction: <type?>, mutation: any) {
    const epic: Epic<RootAction, RootState> = (action$, state$) =>
        action$.pipe(
            filter(isActionOf(actions.request)),
            withLatestFrom(state$),
            mergeMap(([action, state]) =>
                client
                    .mutate({ mutation, variables: { ...action.payload } })
                    .then((result: ApolloQueryResult<P2>) => {
                        return actions.success(result.data);
                    })
                    .catch((error: ApolloError) => {
                        return actions.failure(error);
                    })
           )
       );
    return epic;
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `typesafe-actions@4.3.0` we have added support for creating an explicit type for async actions using `AsyncActionCreator` type.

Here is documentation: https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#asyncactioncreator

In your case you could try to use something like this to infer types from passed async action arg:

```
const createAsyncEpic = <TRequestType extends string, TRequestPayload, TSuccessType extends string, TSuccessPayload, TFailureType extends string, TFailurePayload>(
  asyncAction: AsyncActionCreator<
    [TRequestType, TRequestPayload],
    [TSuccessType, TSuccessPayload],
    [TFailureType, TFailurePayload],
  >,
  mutation: any
) {
...
```